# Abstract Classes in Java and their object variables

Tags: java, abstract-class

i am wondering what happens with object variables in abstract classes in Java. For example if have this abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass{
 private int[] myNumbers;
 public Baseclass(int length){
  myNumbers = new int[length];
 }
 public boolean isOne(int index){
  return myNumbers[index] == 1;
 }
}
```

and i have this real class which extends the BaseClass:

```
public class ArrayClass extends BaseClass{
 private int[] myNumbers; //i have to define it again?
 public ArrayClass(int length){
  super(length); //does this affect my array? I don't think so
 }
 public void setValue(int index, int value){
  if(!isOne(index))
   myNumbers[index] = value;
 }
}
```

I want to define basic operations in my `BaseClass` and do some other stuff in my normal `ArrayClass`. Because i need an `array` in my `BaseClass` i have to define one to work with it in the different methods (obviously).

But in my `ArrayClass` which extends `BaseClass` i have to define another array. I am not sure why this is and if it needs to be this way? I hope you understand what i mean. For example i could utilize the `BaseClass` a second time for this normal class:

```
public class ArrayClass2 extends BaseClass{
 private int[] myNumbers;
 public ArrayClass2(int length){
  super(length);
 }
 public int getValue(int index){
  if(!isOne(index))
   return myNumbers[index];
  else
   return 1;
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you've already read about what `private` mean in Java, but if not - this search may help you - https://www.bing.com/search?q=java+private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has four access types. You can read about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

If you want to expose the field in your base class to its children, you can use *protected* modifier.

Comment: But what if i don't want to expose the variable?

Comment: Well there are two things you can do to reuse your array. The first one using inheritance(like you trying to do now) or with composition. In composition you would instantiate your base class inside array class and delegate array operations to him.

Comment: But note also that base class wont be abstract in that case

Answer (score 1):

The `myNumbers` array needs to be `protected`, not `private` in order to be accessible from within a sub class.

Read more: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm